# Hadoop MapReduce to get data from hibernate ORM

Tags: hibernate, hadoop

I have to process some large amount of data which is persisted in oracle, mysql and postgres and transform it into Cassandra. To solve this I thought of a solution which uses Hadoop MapReduce using hibernate map functions . Is anywhere implementation of InputFormat for Hibernate could you please share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal pattern is to dump your Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL data into HDFS using [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) and run map/reduce on top of HDFS. Then the output you then could stream into Cassandra with something like [hdfs2cass](https://github.com/spotify/hdfs2cass).

Comment: Thanks for answer that will solve my problem for now. This is for knowledge sake has somebody tried the integration with hibernate.